# Can one say "at six months' term" ?

Tags: time

This is in discussing stock market analyses--"we estimate the fair market value will be XXX at six months' term".

Comment: You can say just about anything you like, but I think _the value will be XXX in six months_ is shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: The example sounds pompous at best, pointless jargon next and otherwise in no way useful. If you really as much as possible of that wording what, exactly, does "term" contribute, please? what would be lost in just "we estimate the fair market value will be XXX at six months", please?

Comment: It works. Though brings to me images of gestation and pregnancy where *term* is associated with point in time of development, growth, in other words, maturity as in this case.